# Deploy R on Azure on Linux (centos 8.2.2004)

Tags: r, deployment, centos, shiny-server

I am trying to install R Shiny on Azure , Linux (centos 8.2.2004). Using the manual : https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-r-on-centos-7/

However I can not install packages. I receive error :

```
"ERROR: failed to lock directory ‘/usr/lib64/R/library’ for modifying Try removing ‘/usr/lib64/R/library/00LOCK-Rcpp’ ERROR: dependency ‘Rcpp’ is not available for package ‘later’
* removing ‘/usr/lib64/R/library/later’ ERROR: dependencies ‘Rcpp’, ‘later’ are not available for package ‘promises’
* removing ‘/usr/lib64/R/library/promises’ ERROR: dependencies ‘Rcpp’, ‘promises’, ‘later’ are not available for package ‘httpuv’
* removing ‘/usr/lib64/R/library/httpuv’ ERROR: dependencies ‘httpuv’, ‘later’, ‘promises’ are not available for package ‘shiny’
* removing ‘/usr/lib64/R/library/shiny’

The downloaded source packages are in
        ‘/tmp/RtmpGIfMqF/downloaded_packages’ Updating HTML index of packages in '.Library' Making 'packages.html' ... done Warning messages: 1: In install.packages("shiny") :   installation of package ‘Rcpp’ had non-zero exit status 2: In install.packages("shiny") :   installation of package ‘later’ had non-zero exit status 3: In install.packages("shiny") :   installation of package ‘promises’ had non-zero exit status 4: In install.packages("shiny") :   installation of package ‘httpuv’ had non-zero exit status 5: In install.packages("shiny") :   installation of package ‘shiny’ had non-zero exit status"
```

I have tried to fix the issue however , was able. If you have some ideas, please advice, thanks.

Comment: The package `Rcpp` couldn't be installed. My first try would be to try to install it by itself: `install.packages("Rcpp")` and if this doesn't work see which error messages it generates

Comment: Hi, I tried however have the Error : In install.packages("Rcpp") :
  installation of package ‘Rcpp’ had non-zero exit status

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem finally. There was necessary to delete the folder :

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/lib64/R/library/00LOCK-Rcpp
```

Then tried instal shiny package again and worked fine.